# Making sure a directive runs before all other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way that I can make sure that a specific directive runs before all other custom directives?

I am using a directive to dynamically load CSS files in order to better accommodate my integrators.

The directive looks like this:

```
.directive("includeStylesheet", [ '$log', function($log) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        priority: 1000,
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
          var href = $element.attr("include-stylesheet");
          var filePath = (window.jsPath ? window.jsPath : "styles") + href;
           if ($("link[href=\"" + filePath + "\"]").length === 0){
              if (!document.createStyleSheet){
                  var style = document.createElement("link");
                  style.href = filePath;
                  style.rel = "stylesheet";
                  style.type = "text/css";
                  $("head").append(style);
              } else {
                document.createStyleSheet(filePath);
              }
            };
        }
    }
}])
```

I've been playing around with priority, but even if I set it to `9999` other directives still run first.

My goal here is to make sure no other custom directives fire until the CSS files are loaded.  Is there a way I can do that here?

Comment: Since the CSS file request is async, Angular will not wait for it to finish in order to run the next directive. I don't see a way of doing this.

Comment: I would settle for a way to make sure this directive runs first before all other directives.  Can you see a way to make that happen?

Comment: Running this directive before all the others doesn't mean the CSS file will be loaded before calling the next directive. Let's imagine that the CSS file takes 10 seconds to load. There's no way to force Angular (or any other JS code) to wait 10 seconds before continuing processing. Well... that's not entire true... you can simulate an "active wait" but that would block your entire code, and is a very bad practice...